# Browser of client keeps impersonating as administrator account on IIS 8.0 ASP-MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm using Integrated Windows Authentication for my intranet applications which works great.. but for 1 user (out of +800) the username available in WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name both return a wrong username.

This user is a member of IT that has a normal user account and an administrator account. He's logged in with his normal user account. His iexplore.exe and chome.exe process are running with this account. 2 of my active applications and sharepoint show the correct account. This **3th application** however is showing the **users' administrator acount**.

When the same user logs on to another computer or terminal server, all is correct. When the user accesses the same application in development, all is correct.

Production is running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.0.
Development is running Windows 8.1 with IIS 8.5. IIS is configured to use Windows authentication only, but when enabeling ASP Impersonation, WindowsIdentity gives the exact same result.

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true"/>  <-- only required for ASP impersonation. Added when debugging.
```

Everything has been rebooted & reset. It's the case for every URL in this application. Simple or FQDN, same thing. When adding a new Controller to this MVC application with just

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public string Index()
    {
        return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

It's still the same.. the browser (BOTH Internet Explorer 10 AND Chrome!!) give the wrong username.

This blows my mind..
I guess I could solve it by deleting his windows profile but I really want to know what's causing it.

Can anybody explain and/or help solve this issue?

**[edit 9:30 10/7]**

IIS log is also showing this administrator account

When running iexplore.exe as another user, this user is shown correctly. When logging in on his computer with another user running iexplore.exe as his normal user account, his administrator account pops up.

**[edit 10:00 10/7]**

By now I've reset his internet explorer settings and cleared everything I can clear.. but the problem remains!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user was using the same password for his normal and administrator account. I have requested him to change his administrator account.

After he logged in with this administrator account, logged out and back in with his user account IIS sent a credential request! He then logged in using his normal account and now everything is okay.